# Import-Csv assign record to string (as it would look in csv file opened as notepad)

Tags: powershell-3.0

I don't fully understand yet the value(s) of the `$_` during the `ForEach-Object` loop in `Import-Csv`. So I'm not sure how to merge the records between two csv files (I can get the match found, just not sure how to merge the records).

I thought about assigning both `$_` from the two csv files as a string, and then merging the two strings as a line, but I'm sure how to convert the `$_` into a string without it turning into something weird like `@{column1 = value1_1; column2 = value2_1}` vs `"value1_1","value2_1"`. I'm not even sure if this would be the best solution, or if powershell would support merging both records (which looks like hash tables?).

## The following code errors out at line 62 (`$MergedFileTable += $userInputRecord + $record`):

```
Function Main
{
$userInputCsvTable = Import-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\UserInput.csv'
$userInputCsvFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\UserInput.csv'
$DatabaseCsvTable = Import-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\DatabaseReport.csv'
$DatabaseCsvFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\DatabaseReport.csv'
$DatabaseCustomCsvFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\DatabaseReport_Custom.csv'
$MergedFileTable = @{}
$MergedFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\Merged.csv'

[String]$UserInputColumnIDsTitle = 'IDs'
[String]$UserInputColumnLastNameTitle = 'Last Name'
[String]$UserInputColumnFirstNameTitle = 'First'
[String]$DatabaseColumnUserLoginTitle = 'User Login'
[String]$DatabaseColumnFirstNameTitle = 'First Name'
[String]$DatabaseColumnLastNameTitle = 'Last Name'
[String]$DatabaseColumnUserStatusTitle = 'User Status'
[String]$DatabaseColumnDomain1Title = 'Domain1'
[String]$DatabaseColumnDomain2Title = 'Domain2'
[String]$DatabaseColumnDomain3Title = 'Domain3'
[String]$DatabaseColumnDomain4Title = 'Domain4'
[String]$DatabaseColumnDomain5Title = 'Domain5'
[String]$DatabaseColumnDomain6Title = 'Domain6'

Write-Host "Gathering one list of first and last names from file: $userInputCsvFile..."
[String[]]$userInputColumnsLastAndFirstNames = @()
$userInputCsvTable | ForEach-Object {
    $userInputColumnsLastAndFirstNames += $_.$UserInputColumnLastNameTitle + ' ' + $_.$UserInputColumnFirstNameTitle
}
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Getting Number of Names..."
[Int]$numOfNames = $userInputColumnsLastAndFirstNames.Length
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Creating new Database table only with first and last names in list (side-by-side)..."
[Int]$DisplayCounter = 0
$DatabaseCsvTable | ForEach-Object {
    $DisplayCounter++
    If ($DisplayCounter % 10000 -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host 'On record ' $DisplayCounter
    }
    If ($userInputColumnsLastAndFirstNames -contains ($_.$DatabaseColumnLastNameTitle + ' ' + $_.$DatabaseColumnFirstNameTitle))
    {
        $_
    }
} | Export-Csv $DatabaseCustomCsvFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Creating merged file with duplicate records found..."
$DatabaseCustomCsvTable = Import-Csv $DatabaseCustomCsvFile
$userInputCsvTable | ForEach-Object {
    $userInputRecord = $_
    $firstName = $_.$UserInputColumnFirstNameTitle
    $lastName = $_.$UserInputColumnLastNameTitle
    $matchedTable = $DatabaseCustomCsvTable | Where-Object {($firstName -eq $_.$DatabaseColumnFirstNameTitle) -and ($lastName -eq $_.$DatabaseColumnLastNameTitle)}
    If ($matchedTable)
    {
        ForEach ($record in $matchedTable)
        {
            $MergedFileTable += $userInputRecord + $record
        }
    }
}
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Exporting "
$MergedFileTable | Export-Csv $MergedFile -Force -NoTypeInformation
}

Main
```

## The Error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Scripts\Tests\TestCurrent\test1.ps1:62 char:5
+                 $MergedFileTable += $userInputRecord + $record
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there really was no simple way to do this...

```
# create 2 merged file contents
Write-Host "Searching DB (with each search found)
and creating 2 merged record file contents in memory (one with duplicate records) (one with single records)..."
$UserInputSearchNum = 1
$searchPrintOutputNum = 5
[String]$MergedFileColumnsLine = '"' + $UserInputColumnIDsTitle + '","' + $UserInputColumnFirstNameTitle + '","' + $UserInputColumnLastNameTitle + '","' + $UserInputColumnQLActiveTitle + '","' + $DbColumnUserLoginTitle + '","' + $DbColumnFirstNameTitle + '","' + $DbColumnLastNameTitle + '","' + $DbColumnUserStatusTitle + '","' + $DbColumnAdD1Title + '","' + $DbColumnAdD2Title + '","' + $DbColumnAdD3Title + '","' + $DbColumnAdD4Title + '","' + $DbColumnAdD5Title + '","' + $DbColumnAdD6Title + '"'
$MergedFileContentsSingleRecords = @($MergedFileColumnsLine)
$MergedFileContentsDuplicateRecords = @($MergedFileColumnsLine)
Import-Csv $LocalUserInputCsvReportWithPath | ForEach-Object {
    If ($UserInputSearchNum % $searchPrintOutputNum -eq 0) # Lets user know which search it's on so user can estimate eta on completion
    {
        Write-Host "$UserInputSearchNum/$UserInputNumOfSearches searches complete"
    }
    [String]$userInputRecord = '"' + $_.$UserInputColumnIDsTitle + '","' + $_.$UserInputColumnFirstNameTitle + '","' + $_.$UserInputColumnLastNameTitle + '","' + $_.$UserInputColumnQLActiveTitle + '"'
    $firstAndLastName = $_.$UserInputColumnFirstNameTitle + ' ' + $_.$UserInputColumnLastNameTitle

    $matchedDbRecordTable = Import-Csv $LocalDbCustomReportFileWithPath | Where-Object {$firstAndLastName -eq ($_.$DbColumnFirstNameTitle + ' ' + $_.$DbColumnLastNameTitle)}
    If ($matchedDbRecordTable)
    {
        If ($matchedDbRecordTable.length -gt 1)
        {
            $matchedDbRecordTable | ForEach-Object {
                $MergedFileContentsDuplicateRecords += $userInputRecord + ',"' + $_.$DbColumnUserLoginTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnFirstNameTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnLastNameTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnUserStatusTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD1Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD2Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD3Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD4Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD5Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD6Title + '"'
            } | Out-Null
        } Else {
            $matchedDbRecordTable | ForEach-Object {
                $MergedFileContentsSingleRecords += $userInputRecord + ',"' + $_.$DbColumnUserLoginTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnFirstNameTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnLastNameTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnUserStatusTitle + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD1Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD2Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD3Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD4Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD5Title + '","' + $_.$DbColumnAdD6Title + '"'
            } | Out-Null
        }
    } Else {
        $MergedFileContentsSingleRecords += $userInputRecord + ',"Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found","Not Found"'
    }
    $UserInputSearchNum++
} | Out-Null
Write-Host "Complete."
Write-Host ''
```

Here is the full test script: https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/24649da587afc3d838234ab2398c8f80

Here is the user input file (for testing): https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/864c90325d4e4dc4cf6921bf3b352ff5

Here is the db input file (for testing): https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/81beb4340b9a4d765ebe7b6361d12e30

This only takes the tests a few seconds to run. However, it takes about 60hrs to merge two files with 33000 * 34000 records (while accommodating for duplicates found in both files).

If anyone knows of a library supporting the merge method quicker, it would be of great help. Thanks.